# Math.pow and Infinity

Tags: javascript, math, infinity

There are seven indeterminate forms in maths. Most of them returns NaN in JavaScript. But when i try:

```js
Math.pow( 0, 0 )
```

or

```js
Math.pow( Infinity, 0 )
```

it returns:

```js
1
```

Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: everything to the power of 0 is one - http://www.askamathematician.com/2010/12/q-what-does-00-zero-raised-to-the-zeroth-power-equal-why-do-mathematicians-and-high-school-teachers-disagree/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.8.2.13) says, so it's not a bug:

> 2. If `y` is +0, the result is 1, even if `x` is NaN.

Comment: So there is a disagreement in Maths and Math.pow, maybe it should be reported?

Comment: @Hahi: no there is not, see my answer.

Comment: @Hahi: Seems like `0^0` is a discussion topic rather than something that has a definitive answer. I guess you won't have much luck reporting it since changing it now will cause even more confusion.

Comment: I guess it will stay the same, but it should not cause confusion since it is not too mathematically correct.

Answer (score 5):

No, because anything to the power of zero is one.

Not only is this easier to implement, it is mathematically correct (some mathematicians say `pow(0, 0)` is undefined, but general convention is to take `pow(x, 0) == 1` for **any** x).

On top of that it is in the specification (link officialy stolen from primvdb): http://es5.github.com/#x15.8.2.13

Comment: @nightcracker: "anything" is too general. In calculus 0^0 and infinite^0 are [indeterminate forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Undefined_forms_that_are_not_indeterminate).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a bug. This behaviour is compliance with the [ECMA definition of Javascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).